# Get Network activity

Tags: networking

I have an embedded board running Linux with http, ftp and some other servers.

I need a way to detect when there is no network activity both http, ftp etc.

I will make a linux program, that will run some stuff when there is no network activity for xx minutes.

Comment: The best way to achive this checks is to use Nagios or any other tool for example munin. I dont know how is you http configured you may run nagios on one of the virtual hosts or even better to setup on different host. Also if you have running some of the mail clients you dont even need nagios. You can download ./check_http and ./check_ftp plugins from Nagios community and put those scripts in crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally used [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/).
It presents itself as the network `top` command.

It's based on libpcap, and you can consult the activity by connecting to the web interface.

- You can filter the activity per protocols, such as http, ftp, etc.
- You can display charts to visually see the distribution of your network activity per protocols
- You can have an history with details access informations.

The page I gave display general infos about requirements and a quick overview, but you should check if your embedded board could handle this app.